# Magento alias for helper in global section of config.xml

Tags: magento, config, helper

I am making a module that should have a section in backend. Because I am pretty new I looked into another module config.xml and made mine the same way. 
In the  section helper class was declared with capitalized module name alias, and model and block aliases were lowercase modulenames. I did the same in my module. That's how it looks like now:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <module><class>Namespace_Module_Model</class></module>   
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <Module><class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class></Module>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <module><class>Namespace_Module_Block</class></module>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

In system.xml I declared tab and section with attribute `module="Module"`. 
With these settings all is working just fine, but now I should call my helpers with capital "M". So, I decided to fix this and change capital letter to lowercase. After this change system/configuration throws `Fatal error: Class Mage_Module_Helper_Data not found in some/path/here`. Changing/removing attribute module in system.xml, cleaning cache, relogging doesn't help. I suppose, this capitalized alias was stored somewhere, but I had no luck to find it neither in xml, nor in database.
Btw, is it okay to use  as this alias? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out after some playing with module files. My problem was in source models that I use in my custom settings. They actually made calls to old helper via `Mage::helper('Module')`. 
I changed `Module` to `module` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change in  system.xml the attribute:
"Module" to "module"

```
<menu1 translate="title" module="Module">
```

to

```
<menu1 translate="title" module="module">
```

Dont use capital "M" , after change also have to change in config.xml

```
<helpers><Module>
```

to

```
<helpers><module>
```

By convention, we write the module's  name in lowercase